# embed other map (google,bing) to openstreet map

Tags: google-maps, openstreetmap, bing

I'm currently using google map api v3 but google block my site. So I use my sub-domain temporarily and it work fine.

Now to prevent that happen again I will change my default map to openstreetmap. Now my question is how do i embed the other map like google, bing and etc to OSM.

I'll try this code but what happen is opposite, the OSM is embedded to google map

`map.mapTypes.set("OSM", new google.maps.ImageMapType({
                getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
                    return "http://tile.openstreetmap.org/" + zoom + "/" + coord.x + "/" + coord.y + ".png";
                },
                tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
                name: "OpenStreetMap",
                maxZoom: 18  }));`

Comment: So you want to recycle Google Maps API or use a different webmap framework?

Comment: Nope i will create new one.

Comment: So what does prevent you from using Leaflet or Openlayer and public available OSM services with respect of their tile usage policy?

Answer (score -1):

I found this [link](http://www.slatius.nl/experiments?id=openlayers) and think it is the one i look for. i can switch to OSM, Google, and Bing  Map.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=FALSE&libraries=drawing'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0'></script>


var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {
    projection: new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:900913')
});
var osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
var gmap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google('Google street maps');
var bing = new OpenLayers.Layer.Bing({
    key: 'register your api key at bingmapsportal.com',
    type: 'Road',
    metadataParams: {mapVersion: 'v1'}
});
map.addLayers([osm, gmap, bing]);
map.setCenter(
    new OpenLayers.LonLat(2.2, 54.0).transform(
        new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:4326'), map.getProjectionObject()
    ), 5 );
map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
```

This can switch to a different webmap.  If you have better than this let me know.